# CakePHP login issue

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, phpmyadmin

stackoverflowers. I just meet issue that While I add the login function to my cakePHP website, the account can be added, but the user can not login the system

Appcontroller:

```
namespace App\Controller;

    use Cake\Controller\Controller;

    class AppController extends Controller
    {
        public function initialize()
        {
            $this->loadComponent('Flash');
            $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'authenticate' => [
                    'Form' => [
                        'fields' => [
                            'username' => 'email',
                            'password' => 'password'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'loginAction' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login'
                ]
            ]);

            // Allow the display action so our pages controller
            // continues to work.
            $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
        }
```

Userscontroller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users */
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return void
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['BacklogOrders', 'Orders']
        ]);
        $this->set('user', $user);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return void Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
    }
}
    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
{
    $this->Auth->allow(['add']);
}
}
```

PHPMyadmin table:
3 column:
id
email
password

Password Hashing is already be used.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The 'Auth' Component is configured in AppController. The properties that need to be configured are 'authenticate', 'loginAction', 'loginRedirect' and 'logoutRedirect'. Something like

```
    'loginRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'Pages',
        'action' => 'display',
        'pass[0]' => 'user_home',
    ],
    'logoutRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login',
    ],
```

'loginRedirect' is the page where the users will be landed when they login.
'logoutRedirect' is the page where the users will be landed after they logout.

Comment: Thank you, I just found that this is the database issue.